# Insert element between elements via using date (by date)

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, insert

I wonder how to insert a element via using date ?

**Example :**

```
<time datetime="2013-07-29">2013-07-29</time>
<time datetime="2013-06-14">2013-06-14</time>
<time datetime="2013-06-10">2013-06-10</time>
<time datetime="2013-05-01">2013-05-01</time>
```

**so new element look like... :**

```
<time datetime="2013-06-12">2013-06-12</time>
```

How to insert this new element between `2013-06-14` and `2013-06-10`elements **functionally** ?

**This is my code :**

**HTML :**

```
<input value ="2013-06-12"><button>Add</button>

<time datetime="2013-07-29">2013-07-29</time>
<time datetime="2013-06-14">2013-06-14</time>
<time datetime="2013-06-10">2013-06-10</time>
<time datetime="2013-05-01">2013-05-01</time>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var date = $('input').val();
    var html = $('<time datetime="'+date+'">'+date+'</time>');
    //html.addClass('new').insertAfter('time[datetime="2013-06-14"]');
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/pmREJ/

*If it's ok I want to insert this new element , not sort elements agian.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
 $('button').on('click',function(){
    var dateInput = $('input').val();
    var html = $('<time datetime="'+dateInput+'">'+dateInput+'</time>');

    dateInput = new Date( dateInput);

    $('time').each(function(){
        var tmp = new Date($(this).text());
        if(dateInput.getTime() > tmp.getTime())
        {
           html.addClass('new').insertBefore(this);
            return false;
        }
        html.addClass('new').insertAfter('time:last');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pmREJ/5/

Comment: I mean functionally sorry :(

Comment: define functionally !?

Comment: Yes, like all posible dates

Comment: Ex: add by `2013-06-11` , `1999-01-01` all element gonna inserted right position

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the time list in a sorted way, you could use as below,

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var date = $('input').val();
    var flag = 0;
    var html = $('<time datetime="'+date+'">'+date+'</time>');
    $('time').each(function() {
        var dt = new Date($(this).attr('datetime'));
        var inputdt = new Date(date);
        if( dt.getTime() > inputdt.getTime()) {
           $(this).before(html);
            flag = 1;
            return;
        }
    });
    $('time:last').after(html);
});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6UFmb/2/

Comment: Oh `filter` (Undefined) vs simple `each` (your) , which one is better

Comment: Sorry, found bug. Try : `2009-06-12`

Comment: gonna make some if date is last date ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
    var date = $('input').val(),
        t = new Date(date).getTime(),
        html = $('<time datetime="'+date+'">'+date+'</time>'),
        $f = $('time').filter(function() {
            return new Date(this.innerHTML).getTime() <= t;
        }).first();

    $f.length ? $f.before(html) : $('#wrapper').append(html);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thT2k/

Comment: @l2aelba have you test the other answer with different values?

Comment: Tested 2 values, will test more

Comment: I would use `Date` object since it's more reliable than comparing strings.

Comment: `2011-06-12` will fail

Comment: Your doesn't work if date `2009-06-12` because no `before` element ?

Comment: I have to accecpt @ra_htial, His more understanding for newbies. but I understand your code. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I have update your jsFiddle. With `.each`, you can resolve your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/pmREJ/7/

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var date = $('input').val();
    var html = $('<time class="new" datetime="'+date+'">'+date+'</time>');
    $("time").each(function(){
        if(date > $(this).attr('datetime')){
            $(html).insertBefore($(this));
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```